# Angular controller function not receiving data from directive callback function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building a range slider to be used in a search panel.  I need to return the values set by the slider so it can be applied into the search model for later use.  I have a callback function in my directive and while it does call the controller function correctly, the data isn't getting passed.  Any suggestions are apprecaited

My directive:

```
MyCompany.directive('rangeSlider', [ function() {
var sliderTemplate = "<div>" +
  "<div id='{{rangeData.slider}}'></div>" +
  "<input id='{{rangeData.lowerId}}' " + 
  " type='text' " + 
  " class='span1 text-center'/>" +
  " <div class='middle-marker'>to</div>" +
  "<input id='{{rangeData.upperId}}' " + 
  " type='text' " + 
  " class='span1 text-center pull-right'/>" +
  "</div>";
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  replace: true,
  template: sliderTemplate,
  scope: {
    saveRangeData: '&'
  },
  link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
    scope.rangeData = [];

    scope.rangeData.slider = attrs.slider;
    scope.rangeData.lowerId = attrs.lowerId;
    scope.rangeData.lowerRange = attrs.lowerRange;
    scope.rangeData.upperId = attrs.upperId;
    scope.rangeData.upperRange = attrs.upperRange;

    scope.$watch( element, function(){
      $( "#" + scope.rangeData.slider ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: Number( scope.rangeData.lowerRange ),
      max: Number( scope.rangeData.upperRange ),
      values: [ Number( scope.rangeData.lowerRange ), Number( scope.rangeData.upperRange ) ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#" + scope.rangeData.lowerId ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
      $( "#" + scope.rangeData.upperId ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] );

      scope.saveRangeData({ data: scope.rangeData });
      }
    });

  }
};
}]);
```

Here is my controller function:

```
$scope.saveRangeValues = function( rangeData ) {
  console.log( "saveRangeValues called " );
  console.log( rangeData );
};
```

And the HTML where the directive is called:

```
    <div class="cc-slider span4 pull-right kurz"
  name="val-acc-score"
  data-range-slider
  data-slider="val-acc-score-slider"
  data-lower-id="lower-val-acc-score"
  data-lower-range="0"
  data-upper-id="upper-val-acc-score"
  data-upper-range="10"
  save-range-data="saveRangeValues( rangeData )"></div>
```

As I said previously, the function is getting called and the `console.log` fires off, but the rangeData object is completely empty.  And yes, I checked to make sure that rangeData does have content in the directive.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are naming the parameter `data` when you call inside the directive:

```
scope.saveRangeData({ data: scope.rangeData });
```

If you want to do this, then you have to *rename* the paramter name in the HTML markup:

```
save-range-data="saveRangeValues( data )"></div>
```

The object structure called inside the directive is mapped on to the parameter names in the markup.  [This tutorial](http://www.befundoo.com/university/tutorials/angularjs-directives-tutorial/) explains it well:

> One thing extremely important to note over here is that the object
>   passed as argument should have the same key values (i.e. newRating) as
>   they were passed in the html call to the function. So if you had
>   called the sendRatingToServer() function as sendRatingToServer(rating,
>   stars) it needs to be called in the directive with the same keys i.e.,
>   scope.onRatingSelected({rating: index+1, stars: 5});

Comment: You are AWESOME!   I've been staring at this for 12 hours and I knew I was missing something.  Thanks for the fast reply.  I will accept this answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Comment: This is really help me. I've missed the portion that you mentioned.